# RequireJS load order of dependency

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I define modules below by using RequireJS:

```
define('mod1', ['jquery'], function($){
    return function mod1(){
        //do something
    }
});

define('mod2', ['jquery','jquery.plugin1','mod1'], function($, mod1){
     var mod2 = mod2||{};
     mod2.A = function(){
         return new mod1();
     }
})
```

If define `mod2` like above, when code execute to `new mod1()`, it will throw `mod1 is undefined`. If I define `mod2` like below, works fine.

```
define('mod2', ['mod1','jquery','jquery.plugin1'], function(mod1,$){
     var mod2 = mod2||{};
     mod2.A = function(){
         return new mod1();
     }
})
```

Could anyone explain the reason and how RequireJS works when loading dependency?

Comment: Uhh the `jquery.plugin1` dependency returns `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand why jquery.plugin1 return undefined. if use the snippet 2 , it works well and also can use the jquery.plugin1

Answer (score 1):

This does not work:

```
define('mod2', ['jquery','jquery.plugin1','mod1'], function($, mod1){
```

Because the arguments you give to your anonymous function get the values from the dependency list just before it **in the same order** So the `$` argument gets the value of module `jquery` and the `mod1` argument gets its value from `jquery.plugin1`, and the value of the module `mod1` is passed as the 3rd argument but you'd have to use the automatic variable `arguments` to get it because you did not specify a third argument.

Note that jQuery plugins install themselves by modifying `$` rather than by *returning* a value so the value of the plugin `jquery.plugin1` *as a module* is `undefined`.

When you do this, it works:

```
define('mod2', ['mod1','jquery','jquery.plugin1'], function(mod1,$){
```

Because the order of the dependencies is correctly reflected in the order of the arguments.

Comment: oh, I see.  I just thought that all jquery plugin will be load together and use as '$'. thanks for the explanation.